# Secret Santa Odd Amount of Users PHP Zend

Tags: php

I'm having an issue creating a Secret Santa script when having an Odd amount of users (no issues with Even amount).

The issue is the Final user having two entries. If anyone could explain why this happens I'd be grateful

```php
class Match
{
    protected $startingUsers = [
        "User1",
        "User2",
        "User3",
        "User4",
        "User5",                
    ];

    protected $pairs = [];
    protected $matchedUsers = 0;

    function getPairs(): array
    {
        if ($this->generateUsers($this->startingUsers)) {
            return $this->pairs;
        }

        return [];
    }        
    
    function generateUsers(array $defaultUsers, array $updatedUsers = []): bool
    {
        $users = (!empty($updatedUsers)) ? $updatedUsers : $defaultUsers;

        if (count($users) > 1) {
            if ($this->matchedUsers !== count($this->startingUsers)) {
                // Pick random user and match with current user. Reset array and repeat until 1 or no users left.
                $randomUserIndex = rand(1, count($users) - 1);
                $this->pairs[] = [$users[0], $users[$randomUserIndex]];
                unset($users[$randomUserIndex]);
                unset($users[0]);

                // Remove pair from list so they can't be assigned again. Reset array for 0 based index $users[0]
                $newUsers = array_values($users);
                $this->generateUsers($this->startingUsers, $newUsers);
                $this->matchedUsers += 2;
            }
        }

        // If only one user remains can't allocate a Pair
        if (count($users) === 1) {
            $orderedUsers = array_values($users);
            $this->pairs[] = [$orderedUsers[0], "No Pair"];

            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

$match = new Match();

foreach ($match->getPairs() as $pair) {
    echo "$pair[0] gets $pair[1]";
    echo "\n";
}
```

The final results will look something like User X gets no pair twice over:

```
User1 gets User5
User2 gets User3
User4 gets No Pair
User4 gets No Pair
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to just check the number of people and if its an odd number randomly pick one to remove and then process with the matching process on an even number of people

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside the `generateUsers` method.

When you have 3 users, you unsets the 2 users for which the pair was generated and you call `generateUsers` again (lets call it `generateUsers-LAST`. **THEN**, in the same execution, you check if `$users` has only one element.

During the execution of `generateUsers-LAST`, `$users` contains only one user... Therefore, it add is again. (well, technically speaking, this is the first one).

To solve it, just check if `$users` has more than 1 user before calling `generateUsers`:

```php
function generateUsers(array $defaultUsers, array $updatedUsers = []): bool
{
    $users = (!empty($updatedUsers)) ? $updatedUsers : $defaultUsers;

    if (count($users) > 1) {
        if ($this->matchedUsers !== count($this->startingUsers)) {
            // Pick random user and match with current user. Reset array and repeat until 1 or no users left.
            $randomUserIndex = rand(1, count($users) - 1);
            $this->pairs[] = [$users[0], $users[$randomUserIndex]];
            unset($users[$randomUserIndex]);
            unset($users[0]);

            // Remove pair from list so they can't be assigned again. Reset array for 0 based index $users[0]
            $newUsers = array_values($users);
            // Check that there are two or more users
            if(count($newUsers) > 1){
                $this->generateUsers($this->startingUsers, $newUsers);
            }
            $this->matchedUsers += 2;
        }
    }

    // If only one user remains can't allocate a Pair
    if (count($users) === 1) {
        $orderedUsers = array_values($users);
        $this->pairs[] = [$orderedUsers[0], "No Pair"];

        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
```

However, I think it would be prettier to avoid pairs, but create "random links", like:

```
 - User1 gets User3
 - User3 gets User4
 - User4 gets User2
 - User2 gets User5
 - User5 gets User1
```

This way, there will be no one without match ;)